Why is the load resistance place between source and drain for a CD amplifier in Colpitts Oscillator?
I am reading chapter 12.9 about Common-Drain Colpitts Oscillator in "RF Power Amplifiers" - Marian K. Kazimierczuk. I noticed that he places the load resistor between source and drain. I am usually used to seeing the load resistor between source and GND in a CD amplifier. Furthermore, I would usually place a decoupling capacitor between load resistor and oscillator output as well in order to not mess up the biasing. Anyone has any idea why he would do that?

I also made a couple of simulations and noticed that simulations don't work for  low values of \$R_L\$ when using Kazimierczuk's approach. On the contrary they work when placing the same resistance between source and GND.

The current sink needs to be supplied from somewhere (through RL). Otherwise no energy will flow to LC tank initially after power on.

@MichalPodmanický If I understand correctly. Instead of putting a sinking resistor and load resistor separately, he uses the load as a sinking resistor. Is this something you would commonly use in practice or is it just a textbook simplification?

This theoretical design is correctly using a MOSFET to create a Colpitt's Osc but has a few issues with distortion and no reference on how to unbalance the C values for optimum Q by putting a bigger C across Vgd.
When the FET turns ON a current, with low resistance is injected into a parallel high-impedance tank circuit on the gate which dampens Q and creates a pullup with high slew rate distortion. Thus putting the R to ground pulls down even more current than the CC sink yet raises the Vpp distorted sine wave. So grounding the Nch version adds a huge amount of distortion.
To get a sine wave with low THD, the R must be pulled up so the current is regulated smoother in the FET which only works as a partial half-wave current switch.
Because of the square-law effects on Vgs, you want to reduce the voltage swing here but amplify Vds, so for a practical simulation, I recommend a few things;

Choose a pull-up R not down to reduce distortion, such that I(cc) * R  is less than Vout peak by some x% margin. Vout can be up to 2x to 3x Vdd due to Q and gm.
Choose Cgd 10x bigger than Cd to gnd, then compute C1||C2=Ceff.
AC coupled to the output to R pullup to removes loading on DC CC sink so it can be grounded. This is critical to reduce distortion with a wide range of R.

Next I will create some simulations for say 50 MHz, Beta = 0.05  Vt= 1.5 on 3.3V with CC=100uA.
There is one major drawback to this design. The DC constant current, CC sink produces bipolar voltages.
EDIT: But with an AC coupled load , now it is possible to make the CC sink unipolar positive voltages.
Revised design spec to > 1 mA to drive Zo of LC filter with 9Vpp output (distorted)
Ver 1.0

Ver 2.0 switched load to Vdd (pullup) as in the original figure.

If you don't care about distortion use an RC Inverter Osc for a square(ish) wave...
Look at Vgs = 1.6 pk, Vt = 1.5V and low duty less than half-wave Id current wave means output is a high(ish) impedance LC tank circuit so R load cannot be lowered too much without distorting the sinewave.
You tell how much THD is in an AC- coupled sinewave by looking at the ratio of Vavg/Vpk = THD. Ver 3 below is better than -60 dB THD.

1

It's a text book simplification. Many times you see simplifications similar to this. For instance, on many BJT text book simplifications they omit the base biasing because, for AC analysis none are needed to explain how the two capacitors and inductor work together. The same is true for your circuit; the MOSFET isn't specified and could be a depletion type device requiring no explicit bias resistors or, if a regular MOSFET, it will need those resistors but, in truth we don't care when presented with a topological circuit like this.
Personally I don't like to see the load resistor tied to Vdd but, maybe the text that surrounds the image makes a justification for this. For AC signal analysis it doesn't matter of course.

Are you sure you think it is a JFET ? https://www.wikiwand.com/en/search?q=jfet   The load is all about pulsed FET injection and it is better not to pull down with R than a high impedance current sink. thus -1

That is not a JFET symbol thus wrong interpretation.

Thanks Tony @D.A.S.
